# Unable to select correct element with XSLT in BPEL

Tags: xml, xslt, bpel

I have two variables. One is Input, second is DB. In for loop, I try to match INPUT/numberVPN with DB/userid (they are sorted differently, but all numbers from input exist in DB variable).

Now once I find it, I want the current DB/OLD_PID to be mapped into Input/profileCode, not the first one. I'm always getting just 1st, 2nd, ...

INPUT Variable (removed unneeded/classified data):

```
<ns7:VPNProvisioning>
    <VPNScenario>           
        <profileCodeCollection>
            <profileCode>Profil3</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil3</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil3</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil3</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil3</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil3</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil3</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil3</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil3</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil3</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil3</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil3</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil3</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil3</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil3</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil3</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil4</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil4</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil4</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil4</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil4</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil4</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil4</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil4</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil4</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil4</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil4</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil4</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil4</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil4</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil4</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil4</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil4</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil4</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil4</profileCode>
            <profileCode>Profil4</profileCode>
        </profileCodeCollection>
        <numberVPNCollection>
            <numberVPN>0099962330481</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099962342864</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099962342865</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099962342867</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099962342868</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099962342869</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099962342870</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099962342871</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099962342873</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099962342882</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099962342883</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099962343623</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099962343624</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099962343625</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099962343626</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099962343627</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099932406802</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099932618450</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099932691124</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099932691244</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099932691373</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099932691376</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099932691474</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099932691491</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099932691531</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099961153082</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099961153083</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099961153084</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099961153085</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099961153318</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099961166999</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099961166388</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099961176716</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099961473357</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099961473368</numberVPN>
            <numberVPN>0099962336527</numberVPN>
        </numberVPNCollection>
    </VPNScenario>
</ns7:VPNProvisioning>
```

DB Variable:

```
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutputCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/fget_esinfo4vpnterminate">
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>032/406802</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>100002</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>032/618450</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>100002</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>032/691124</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>100002</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>032/691244</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>100002</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>032/691373</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>100002</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>032/691376</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>100002</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>032/691474</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>100002</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>032/691491</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>100002</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>032/691531</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>100002</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>061/153082</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>061/153083</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>061/153084</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400004</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>061/153085</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>061/153318</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>061/166387</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>061/166388</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>061/176716</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>061/473357</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>061/473368</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>062/330481</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>062/336527</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400004</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>062/342864</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>062/342865</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>062/342867</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>062/342868</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>062/342869</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>062/342870</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>062/342871</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>062/342873</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>062/342882</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>062/342883</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>062/343623</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>062/343624</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>062/343625</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>062/343626</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
<fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
    <USERID>062/343627</USERID>
    <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
</fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
```

XSLT code from BPEL:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<ns6:VPNProvisioning>
  <VPNScenarioCollection>
    <VPNScenario>
      <profileCodeCollection>
        <xsl:for-each select="$esinfo4vpnterminate_OutputVariable.fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutputCollection/db:fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutputCollection/db:fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput">
          <xsl:if test='concat("00999",substring-before(substring(db:USERID,2.0),"/"),substring-after(db:USERID,"/")) = /ns1:ORDCOMPLETE/ns1:VPNProvisioning/VPNScenario/numberVPNCollection/numberVPN'>
            <profileCode>
              <xsl:value-of select="db:OLD_PID"/>
            </profileCode>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </profileCodeCollection>
    </VPNScenario>
  </VPNScenarioCollection>
</ns6:VPNProvisioning>
```

So my goal is:

For each number in input variable, find the same in db variable (ignore different format, it's parsed correctly). Then, from the node where it finds the match, take old_pid and put in profile code in input variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using node name, I had to use '.' to select current value in the for loop. The solution was:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/ns1:ORDCOMPLETE/ns1:VPNProvisioning/VPNScenario/numberVPNCollection/numberVPN">
          <xsl:variable name="foo" select="."/>
          <xsl:variable name="dbout"
                        select="$esinfo4vpnterminate_OutputVariable.fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutputCollection/db:fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutputCollection/db:fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="$dbout">
            <xsl:if test="concat('00999', substring-before(substring(./db:USERID, 2.0), '/'), substring-after(./db:USERID, '/')) = $foo">
              <profileCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="./db:OLD_PID"/>
              </profileCode>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about BPEL, but your goal can be transformed more or less directly to xslt, simplified:

- for each number in input:
- find the same in db-variable and take old_pid:

For a working example, I had to remove some namespaces and assume that INPUT was input to the xslt and not in a variable, but this is a starting point. I saved your INPUT as a separate file, and ran the following xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
    xmlns:db="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/fget_esinfo4vpnterminate">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="db">
        <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutputCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/fget_esinfo4vpnterminate">
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>032/406802</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>100002</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>032/618450</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>100002</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>032/691124</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>100002</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>032/691244</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>100002</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>032/691373</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>100002</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>032/691376</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>100002</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>032/691474</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>100002</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>032/691491</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>100002</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>032/691531</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>100002</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>061/153082</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>061/153083</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>061/153084</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400004</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>061/153085</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>061/153318</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>061/166387</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>061/166388</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>061/176716</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>061/473357</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>061/473368</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>062/330481</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>062/336527</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400004</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>062/342864</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>062/342865</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>062/342867</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>062/342868</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>062/342869</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>062/342870</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>062/342871</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>062/342873</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>062/342882</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>062/342883</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>062/343623</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>062/343624</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>062/343625</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>062/343626</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
            <fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
                <USERID>062/343627</USERID>
                <OLD_PID>400001</OLD_PID>
            </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput>
        </fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutputCollection>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <VPNProvisioning>
            <VPNScenarioCollection>
                <VPNScenario>
                    <profileCodeCollection>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="/VPNProvisioning/VPNScenario/numberVPNCollection/numberVPN" />
                    </profileCodeCollection>
                </VPNScenario>
            </VPNScenarioCollection>
        </VPNProvisioning>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="numberVPN">
        <xsl:variable name="number" select="concat('0',substring(text(),6,2),'/',substring(text(),8))"/>
        <profileCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($db)/db:fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutputCollection/db:fget_esinfo4vpnterminateOutput[db:USERID = $number]/db:OLD_PID"/>
        </profileCode>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I had to use the [node-set extension function](http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/) to be able to use a variable in a select.